# NumberFormatter: allow "," and "." as the decimal separator

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, nsnumberformatter, numberformatter

I'm using `NumberFormatter` to format and validate user's currency input.
Since some people are using `,` and the others `.` irrespective of the selected locale, I'd like to have both of those symbols treated as the decimal separator when processing an input (i.e. formatting a `String` to `Number`).

How can I achieve this?

My current `NumberFormatter` configuration is as follows:

```
    private lazy var currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
        currencyFormatter.currencySymbol = ""
        currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        currencyFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        return currencyFormatter
    }()
```

Should I use multiple formatters to achieve the result I want?

**The result**

I'd like to have numbers `5,34` and `5.34` to be treated as valid and converted to the appropriate `NSNumber`. However, I'd like to still be able to reject `5.34lksdfns` as invalid.

Comment: How would you interpret  "5,345" if the comma can be a decimal separator or a thousands separator?

Comment: The correct way to do it is to use the appropriate locale on your formatter before parsing the string (for example `en_US` uses `.` for decimals while `el_GR` uses `,`). I know that sometimes this is not possible due to the nature of your data and while I am **_not_** suggesting that you should do so in a production app, you could just "normalize" your input before passing it to the formatter (maybe by replacing commas with dots)

Comment: I think the only way to make this work automatically this is to not allow a thousand separator to be used but that is probably not a good restriction, maybe better to have a setting so the user can override the used decimal separator specifically for your app.

Comment: @MartinR in this case there is no ambiguity. It should be interpreted as "5.345"

Comment: To allow `.` & `,` both as the decimal separator for the same locale doesn't make any sense. As @MartinR also pointed out, you won't have the way to interpret the decimal & thousand separator then. Can you differentiate the input `5,345.99` for the two cases: (i) user who uses `.` as the decimal, (ii) user who uses `,` as the decimal?

Comment: hello @RichardTopchii do you have any updates on this ? I also would love to know the solution because i am looking for the same behaviour

Comment: @MahmoudZinji the solution is to use 2 Number Formatters and get a result from the one that returns any value, cause the other will fail.